# I can't set background picture in www

Tags: html, css

Iam trying to set up picture for background on my website at the moment iam using localhost for testing but i can't set it. I place the picture in the same file as index.html is. Name is also the same as in code "background2.jpg".

This is my code in css file:

```
body
{
background:url("background2.jpg") no-repeat center center   fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Comment: any errors on the console? Also, I know you said filename is the same but `jpg` instead of `jpeg` has caused me to lose my sanity a few times.

Comment: What if you call your picture directly from the browser (e.g. http://localhost/background2.jpg)?

Comment: The code block is correct

Comment: Whatever the problem is, [it isn't with that code](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ebth/)

Comment: The path to image is relative to CSS file, not your HTML. Maybe they're not in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created index.html with your css and my image, that is in the same folder, and it's works. Probably you have problems with your webserver settings.

Answer (score 0):

The code is just fine. If all files are in the same directory than thats fine to.

Maby a to obvious thing to say but it could very well be that you have the old webpage in your case. Have you tried pressing Ctrl+F5? This refreshes your cash memory.

Answer (score -1):

you need this

```
body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

try this..

Comment: Why? If you leave the dimensions of the body element alone, it will cover the browser window (at a minimum).

Comment: Iam using a wamp, that can be a problem. What i need to check?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
body
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background:url("background2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Comment: Like what? What have you changed? Is the change of height and width the only thing you have done? Because that won't help.

Comment: By "read what i changed" do you mean I should place spot-the-difference across 13 lines of code? I tried the code in the original question, and *that* works too, so this can't improve anything.

Comment: You shouldn't ask what i changed since its pretty easy to spot. We dont know his html settings or even which browser he use. Have you tried every possibility? I dont think so.

Comment: So you think that some other code that wasn't shared is altering the dimensions of the body? That would be *one* possibility (although not one I think is very likely), but the solution then would be to remove that code and not try to override it without knowing what the specificity of the other selector is.

Comment: I wrote a simple answer from a GUESS how he structured it. Unless he share more information i cant help him.